# Why are images displaying in the incorrect way in JavaScript onClick event?

Tags: javascript

I have three images image1, image2, image3. I want this to happen:

```
image1 appears when the page loads
image1 clicked-->image2 displays
image2 clicked-->image3 displays
image3 clciked-->image1 displays
```

At the moment this is what actually happens:

```
image1 clicked-->image3 displays
image3 clicked-->image1 displays
image1 clicked-->image2 displays
image2 clicked-->image3 displays
image3 clciked-->image1 displays
```

...and the cycle continues correctly.

Why is image 2 not being loaded on the first cycle? I have attached my Javascript code below. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imagecentre"><img id="myButton" src="image1.jpg"/></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
            i = 1;
        // event handler
        document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() 
            if (i==images.length-1){
            this.src=images[0];
            i=0;
            }

            else {
            this.src=images[i+1];
            i++;
            }

        }, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `i` must be set to 0 on page load, additionally you're missing an opening `{` for the click callbak.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried setting it 0 and it wasn't working but it turns out that its the missing { that was cousing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set `i = 0` initially.

```
   // i must be 0 initially.
   var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
       i = 0;
```

And, you're missing an opening `{` for the callback function, as pointed out by Jono.

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
   ...
}, false);
```

Comment: That seemed like the solution to me too but when I do that the code stops working (no change in image on click).

Comment: You're missing an opening `{` for your click callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your logic, when the page loads, i == 1. That means onclick the "else" condition is firing, hence loading images[2] (which is the 3rd image in the array)

Answer (score 1):

Change `i` to be 0 on page load, and add missing `{` to the click callback function.

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
        i = 0;
    // event handler
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (i==images.length-1){
        this.src=images[0];
        i=0;
        }

        else {
        this.src=images[i+1];
        i++;
        }

    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imagecentre"><img id="myButton" src="image1.jpg" width="100px"/></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
            i = 0;
        // event handler
        document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (i==images.length-1){
            this.src=images[0];
            i=0;
            }

            else {
            this.src=images[i+1];
            i++;
            }

        }, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

Place `i=0` instead of `i=1`